# How does the pressure inside a pipe drop for a compressible gas (hydrogen)?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, physical-chemistry, hydrogen

It is about turbulent compressible fluid, in this case, hydrogen gas.

I have hydrogen gas at Ti = 25 K, pi = 3 bars, and ṁi = 0.001 kg/s (so 2.214 m/s) at the inlet of the tube. The pipe is 12.7 mm in diameter. The flow is turbulent (Re = 78767), friction factor is f = 0.0189. The outside atmosphere around the pipe is at 210 K.

After 0.1 m, the temperature reaches Tf ~ 40 K (due to the fact that we have a heat transfer of 223 W here) at the outlet of the pipe, and we want to know the pressure and ṁ at the outlet of the pipe.

Things I have tried of:

- Ideal gas law: applying PV=nRT on each side (inlet, and outlet) but it's not working, it gives me a final pressure of 4.8 bars.
- Darcy-Weisbach equation, but it gave me a drop pressure of 1 Pa which seems incorrect.
- Bernoulli’s equation but it gives me incorrect results (Pf = 2.65 or 2.24 bars) because the theory state that the fluid is incompressible.

If you have any suggestions, equations, etc., It’ll be great.

Comment: Due to the continuity equation, your outlet mass flow rate must equal your inlet mass flow rate, assuming that there are no streams entering or leaving the tube along its length.  Do you have a pressure measurement at the tube outlet?  Can you verify that the tube is only 0.1 m long?  What material is it made of?  Does the tube exhaust to atmosphere?  Why do you want to calculate pressure drop rather than measure it?  How precise must your answer be?  If you need high precision, what process requires it?  Please provide a few more details.

Comment: Hi David,

This idea is to calculate and know the pressure every 0.1 m for a straight pipe of 3 m. The pipe is made of a smooth SS 316 L.  

For your questions:  
    - We don't have a pressure measurement (and cannot make a measurement unfortunately), we just know that the pressure should be around the initial pressure.  
    - No at the end of the tube, we'll inject the hydrogen, we'll not release it to the atm.
    - The answer should be precise but not necessarily accurate ( a precision of +/- 5 % is ok).

Comment: In my opinion, the Darcy-Weisbach  equation is the correct answer.  At the VERY low gas velocities that you are dealing with, you can expect the pressure drop to be very low.  Based on my industrial experience as a chemical engineer, I witnessed somewhat larger pressure drops for gases flowing at 50-100 m/s over much longer distances than 3 m, so very low gas flow velocities over such a short length can be expected to give you a very low pressure drop.

Comment: David. So the results we calculated, a drop of a few Pa should be correct using Darcy-Weisbach. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flow equation is $$\frac{dp}{dx}=-\frac{\rho v^2}{2}\frac{f}{D}$$But, from continuity, $$v=\frac{\dot{4m}}{\pi \rho D^2}$$Combining these equation gives:$$\frac{dp}{dx}=-\frac{8\dot{m}^2 }{\pi^2 \rho D^5}f$$But, from the idea  l gas law, $$\rho=\frac{pM}{RT}$$Substituting into the previous equation gives:$$\frac{dp^2}{dx}=-\frac{16\dot{m}^2R }{\pi^2 M D^5}(fT)$$
Where the fraction on the rhs is constant, but where f and T are functions of x because of the axial variation in temperature and its effect on Reynolds number (through viscosity): $$
Re=\frac{4\dot{m}}{\pi D\mu}$$ So for a compressible gas, we are integrating pressure squared rather than pressure to the first power.

Comment: Hello Chet Miller,

Thank you for your answer and all the equations provided, you've completely answered my question!